# Que herramienta/s puedo usar para descargar una grafica si uso chart.js

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, chart.js

Hola muy buenas compañeros, mas que nada eso uso `laravel 5.6` y `Bootstrap 3.3.7` junto con `chart.js (ultima version)` y bueno que herramienta es buena para poder yo esa misma grafica que me muestra pasarla a pdf ara luego descargarla, cualquier cosa dejo mi codigo.

```js
<script>
var cadena = "";
var datos = "";
var respuestas = "";
var datosSeparados = "";
var frecuencias = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  @foreach($preguntas as $p)
  var respuestas{{$p->id_pesp}} = [];
  @if($p->tipo != "1" && $p->tipo != "2")
  if($("#graf{{$p->id_pesp}}")){
    cadena = ""
    @foreach($resultados as $res)
    @if($res->id_pesp == $p->id_pesp)
    cadena += "{{$res->respuesta}};";
    @endif
    @endforeach
    datos = cadena.substring(0, cadena.length - 1);
    alert(datos);
    datosSeparados = datos.split(';');
    @foreach($respuestas as $r)
    var f = 0;
    @if($r->id_pesp == $p->id_pesp)
    respuestas{{$p->id_pesp}}.push("{{$r->respuestas}}");
    for(var i = 0; i < datosSeparados.length; i++){
      if(datosSeparados[i]=={{$r->id_res}}){
        f++;
      }
    }
    frecuencias.push(f);
    @endif
    @endforeach
    var grafica = $('#graf{{$p->id_pesp}}');
    
    var grafica = new Chart(grafica, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: respuestas{{$p->id_pesp}},
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Encuesta Especifica',
          data: frecuencias,
          lineTension: 0,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      }
    });
  }
  @endif
  @endforeach
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
          @foreach($preguntas as $p)
          @if($p->tipo != "1" && $p->tipo != "2")
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
              <label>Encuesta de Satisfaccion</label><br><br>
              <label>Pregunta: {{$p->pregunta}}</label>
              <canvas id="graf{{$p->id_pesp}}"></canvas>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endif
          @endforeach
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
              <label>Pregunta: Encuesta Básica</label>
              <canvas id="grafica" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Gracias por su ayuda compañeros, aun así sigo intentando buscar en la red, cualquier avance tenga estaré editando mi pregunta o en caso de resolverlo posteare la respuesta, saludos!.

Comment: puedes utilizar los plugins de Highcharts, son de pago, pero solo vas a tener que buscar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas:

- una librería  [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)
- un canvas donde dibujar el chart
- un boton para hacer click y poder sacar la imagen con [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) en formato PNG
- Mentirle al pdf diciendole que es una imagen JPG
- Llamar al PDF save para que lo descargue

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};

var frecuencias = [
  randomScalingFactor(),
  randomScalingFactor(),
  randomScalingFactor(),
  randomScalingFactor(),
  randomScalingFactor(),
  randomScalingFactor(),
];
          
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var downloadBtn = document.getElementById('downloadBtn');
  
  var canvas = document.getElementById("graf01");
  var grafica = new Chart(
    canvas, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ['Hay','papa','manzana','batata','señoooraaa','baratooo'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Encuesta Especifica',
          data: frecuencias,
          lineTension: 0,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      }
    });


    downloadBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.toISOString();
      // only jpeg is supported by jsPDF
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
      var pdf = new jsPDF();
      pdf.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 0, 0);
      pdf.save(n+"-graf01.pdf");
    }, false);
  });
```

```css
body {
  background:#fafafa;
}
.container {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 820px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#downloadBtn {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="chart">
   <div>
     <canvas id="graf01" width="640" height="400"></canvas><br />
     <button id="downloadBtn" class="btn btn-info">Descargar chart como PDF</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, ya solo queda adaptarlo a corde lo que quiero imprimir, Muchas gracias por la ayuda